# How do I maximize my expected utility of wealth?

Tags: portfolio-optimization, returns, modern-portfolio-theory, asset-pricing, utility-theory

Suppose I have a utility function say $U(p)=p^{1/2}$
and I bet on a basketball game.
I have my initial investment, payouts and probabilities of winning, how can I determine the maximum I need to bet on each basketball team to maximize my utility function? I have been looking through the theory for this and im not sure. I think I have to find the expected payoffs for each team and then substitute them into my utility?

Comment: Assuming p is your payoff, how do you weigh this for losses? No “they’re imaginary“ gags intended :-)

Comment: Presumably you will not bet your whole wealth on a basketball game. So what matters is a small fluctuation in wealth $\Delta p$ (positive or negative) added to your initial wealth $p_0$. (So what matters is the *derivatives* of the square root function at $p_0$.) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risk_aversion

Comment: @noob2 okay so if I had 1000 dollars i saved up only to bet on the game and i want to use it all. each bet costs 50 dollars to make, the payoff and probability for miami heat to win is 40 dollars at 0.3 and for the lakers its 10 dollars at 0.6, to find the optimal bets to make for each game i would need to substitute my initial 1000 + some investment level -50 into my function and find that investment level? struggling to understand the logic here .

Comment: Your goal function is then $p(1000+k90)^{.5}+(1-p)(1000-k50)^{.5}$. Maximize wrt $k$.

Comment: ...in other words *Maximize Expected Utility*.

Comment: @Kermittfrog Ahh okay, do I not take away my initial investment of 50 from each outcome within the root?

Comment: Ah OK, if "p" is wealth-utility and not payoff-utility, then Kermitfrog's solution is exactly how I'd solve this. Strikes me, though, that this utility function makes me very complacent when I'm rich versus very cautious when I'm poor. I'm not sure I'd objectively bet consistently using this function, as opposed to become heavily path-dependent.

Comment: @demully could you explain how he gets 90k and 50k? I would of thought I where to bet K on Miami heat then 50-k on the lakes, where does he get 90k and 50k?

Comment: @all: Yep, i forgot the other half of the bet :(

Comment: @Kermittfrog thanks a lot pal, could you talk through how you constructed the function if you dont mind

Comment: Utility if win = (Cap + Bet * Odds) ^ Risk. Utility if lose = (Cap - Bet) ^Risk. So expected utility if p(win)=P is P * Uw + (1-P) * Ul. Max Utility, zero derivative wrt Bet will give you a P * Risk * Odds * (Cap + Bet * Odds)^(Risk-1) = (1-P) * Risk * (Cap - Bet)^(Risk-1) equation. Logarithm to solve for Bet.